# ruby shift - how to shift an array without shifting an array that it was assigned to

Tags: ruby

I assign one array to another:

```
a = ['who','let','the','dogs','out']
b = a
b.shift
```

b and a now both are

```
["let", "the", "dogs", "out"].
```

I would like for a to still be

```
["who","let", "the", "dogs", "out"]
```

How can you mutate b without mutating a?

Also, why does this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

That's because `b` and `a` references to the same object in the memory:

```
a = ['who','let','the','dogs','out']
b = a
a.object_id == b.object_id
# => true
```

`b` needs to be another array object, so I would create a clone of `a`:

```
a = ['who','let','the','dogs','out']
b = a.dup
a.object_id == b.object_id
# => false

b.shift
# => "who"
b
# => ["let", "the", "dogs", "out"]
a
# => ["who", "let", "the", "dogs", "out"]
```

Comment: It is advised to use `.dup` instead of `.clone`, for simple usage like this. There difference between them is very subtle (`.clone` copies the singleton methods and maintains the `frozen?` status of the object) -- but for 99% of usages, like this, the methods are equivalent, but `.dup` is slightly faster.

Comment: _"b references to a"_ – nitpicking, but that sounds like chained variables: `b → a → obj`. It's actually more like `a → obj ← b`, i.e. both reference the same object, not each other.

Comment: @TomLord and Stefan: Your are right. I updated my answer. Thx

Answer (score 1):

When you say:

```
b = a
```

You are saying let `b` point to the same object as `a`. You are not saying copy the contents of `a` into `b`. For that you would need to use the method `clone`.
In addition to guitarman's answer, there is an array method that will return the rest of the array after shifting without changing the original array. This only works if you don't care what you are shifting/dropping off the array and are only concerned about the remaining items.

```
1 > a = ['who','let','the','dogs','out']
 => ["who", "let", "the", "dogs", "out"] 
2 > b = a.drop(1)
 => ["let", "the", "dogs", "out"] 
3 > a
 => ["who", "let", "the", "dogs", "out"] 
4 > b
 => ["let", "the", "dogs", "out"]
```